# C# WebBrowser Invoke issue

Tags: c#

I am logging into facebook using a web browser. Everything works, but the problem is when I invoke the button click I need to check if the password is correct but, the check seems to happen before the button is invoked which makes no sense at all because the checking code is after the invoke.

```
private void Facebook_Login(String username, String password)
    {
        webBrowser1.Url = new Uri("http://m.facebook.com");

        while (webBrowser1.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete) Application.DoEvents();

        HtmlElementCollection inputs = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");
        foreach(HtmlElement input in inputs)
        {
            if (input.GetAttribute("name") == "email") 
            {
                input.SetAttribute("value", "jamesjeffery@hotmail.co.uk");
            }
            if (input.GetAttribute("name") == "pass")
            {
                input.SetAttribute("value", "kelaroostj"); // dont worry that pass wont work lol.
            }
            if (input.GetAttribute("name") == "login")
            {
                input.InvokeMember("click");
            }
        }

        while (webBrowser1.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete) Application.DoEvents();

        HtmlElementCollection bs = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("b");
        foreach(HtmlElement b in bs)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(b.InnerHtml);
        }

        Log_Message("Logged into Facebook with: jamesjeffery@hotmail.co.uk");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are looping trough all HTML Elements. You just have this code in the "logical" order, it does not mean that the HTMLElementCollection has it also.

If the HTML button is the first element in the row, the first thing that will happen is that the button is clicked.

```
HtmlElement Username = Browsers[0].Document.GetElementById("name");
HtmlElement Password = Browsers[0].Document.GetElementById("pass");
HtmlElement LoginBtn = Browsers[0].Document.GetElementById("login");

Username.SetAttribute("value", "jamesjeffery@hotmail.co.uk");
Password.SetAttribute("value", "kelaroostj");
LoginBtn.InvokeMember("click");
```

This is assuming that the ID of the elements is as supplied above.